# How to implement an "expires after" side effect in Lagom?

Tags: scala, akka, cqrs, event-sourcing, lagom

I'm approaching Lagom + CQRS/Event Sourcing for the first time and I would like to implement a behaviour like:

1. A service call is executed ( for example via a REST API call )
2. A command is run and triggers an event that mutates the state ( for example starts some kind of timer ).
3. After a pre-defined interval, the timer should expire so a new event should be triggered ( without other external commands ) to mutate the state in order to invalidate the timer.

The first two steps are straightforward, but once I trigger the TimerStartedEvent and mutate the state, how do I "schedule" an event after a fixed amount of time? How do I implement the third step?

Comment: I'm not personally familiar with Lagom but since you listed Akka in your tags I'll suggest the Akka Scheduler to schedule a timeout message to your Actor if this is applicable to your situation.

I used this in a Job Orchestration application I wrote this past year that is similar in behavior: call a REST API, once the REST API completes a Completed action should trigger, but at the same time as the REST call use an Akka Scheduler to schedule a timeout message. Whichever comes in first to the target Actor defined how that call terminated

Comment: @MattEdge that's a good idea! Lagom is built on top of Akka so that's why I listed it in my tags. The only "drawback" is that this external service should call some API to the 1st service to communicate the timeout, so in CQRS terms it should execute a command to trigger an event that mutates the state. Is that the "correct" way or the event should be generated without a specific command from the outside?

Comment: We had the event generated internally after the results were routed through the REST API to the associated Actor which then regenerated the command. But if the Timeout occurred first the Actor terminated and the API could not query the appropriate actor (we logged that out for tracking purposes).

Comment: @MattEdge thank you very much...the Akka Scheduler was the right call!

Comment: Excellent! Glad to hear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possibile implementation ( actually on the [online-auction-scala sample code](https://github.com/lagom/online-auction-scala/blob/master/bidding-impl/src/main/scala/com/example/auction/bidding/impl/AuctionScheduler.scala) itself ).

Because Lagom it's built on top of Akka, it injects the ActorSystem, so you can use the `system.scheduler.schedule` call to schedule something in the future.

To answer the CQRS part of the question, the sample code does something like:

```
system.scheduler.scheduler(offset, delay) {
  checkFinishBidding()
}

checkFinishBidding() = {
  registry.refFor[Entity](id).ask(SomeCommand)
}
```

So when the time fires, you can dequeue the entity ref from the registry and run a command just like a normal service call.

Comment: This is a good solution, but there's one thing to watch out for: the example code in the online auction app is not yet cluster-aware. That means that if you run the service on multiple nodes (recommended for resilience) then the scheduled task will run on all of them. To avoid that, you can use an Akka [Cluster Singleton](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/cluster-singleton.html).

Comment: Also, I think you can accept your own answer if you're happy with it :)